# Making A Meteor Subdocument Reactive

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I have a collection of Items that can be marked as "read" by my users.

In order to mark a collection as "read", a subdocument is added:

```
"readby": [
    {
      "action": "read",
      "owner": "w5XzMrCCJJfDxCn6d"
    }
  ]
```

I then use the following helper to set up an array and push any "read" entries that match the current owner. If the array has a length bigger than 0, the helper returns "true" and we know the logged in user has read this item:

```
itemHasBeenRead() {
    var subscribers = [];
    var readItems = this.readby;

    if(!readItems) {
        return false;
    }

    var readiness = readItems.forEach(function(currentSubscriber) { 
      // loop over current users expenses
      var newSubscriber = { owner: currentSubscriber.owner };

      if (currentSubscriber.owner == Meteor.userid()) {
            subscribers.push(newSubscriber);
      }
    });

    return subscribers && subscribers.length > 0
}
```

This all works perfectly BUT as I understand it, subdocuments aren't reactive in Meteor, so the code doesn't pick up changes reactively. Refresh the page and it works fine.

Is there a way to do this reactively, rather than just on page load?

--

Edits as requested:

--

**Template code:**

```
{{#each playlists}}
      <h2 class="playlistheader">{{playlistName}}<span class="badge badge-playlist badge-playlist-first badge-primary"><i class="fas fa-users playlist-fa"></i>{{numberOfSubscribers}} enrolled</span>{{#unless isPlaylistOwner}}{{#unless userIsSubscribed}}<span class="badge badge-playlist badge-success subscribe-unsubscribed" data-id="{{this._id}}"><i class="far fa-heart playlist-fa"></i>Enrol</span>{{/unless}}{{#if userIsSubscribed}}<span class="badge badge-playlist badge-success subscribe-subscribed" data-id="{{this._id}}"><i class="fas fa-heart playlist-fa"></i>Enrolled</span>{{/if}}{{/unless}}


        <span class="badge badge-playlist badge-completion" data-id="{{this._id}}"><i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="margin-right:3px;"></i>0/6 items marked complete</span>


        {{#if isPlaylistOwner}}<span class="badge badge-playlist badge-danger badge-delete" data-id={{this._id}}><i class="fas fa-ban playlist-fa"></i>Delete</span>{{/if}}</h2>
      <span class="playlist-subheader">{{playlistPrivacyType}} collection by {{playlistOwnerName}}</span>
      <div class="row" style="display:inherit; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:8px;">
        <div class="scrolling-wrapper-playlist">
          {{#if isPlaylistOwner}}
          <div class="playlist-product playlist-product-add" data-playlistid="{{playlistid}}">
            <div class="clampcontainer">
              <div class="add-playlist-plus" data-playlistid="{{playlistid}}">+</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {{/if}}

          {{#each playlistItems this._id}}
          <div class="playlist-product" data-id={{this._id}}>
            {{#if isPlaylistItemOwner}}
            <div class="playlist-product-delete">
              <i class="fas fa-times-circle product-delete"></i>
            </div>{{/if}}
          <div class="playlist-product-overlay" id="overlay-{{this._id}}" style="opacity:0;">
            <div class="playlist-product-overlay-description">
              "{{itemDescription}}"</div>
          <div class="playlist-product-overlay-icons">
            {{#unless itemHasBeenRead}}
            <i class="far fa-check-circle playlist-circle"></i>
            {{/unless}}
            {{#if itemHasBeenRead}}
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle playlist-circle"></i>
            {{/if}}
          {{#if hasPrice}}
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart playlist-cart"></i>
{{/if}}
            <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt playlist-external"></i>

          </div>
</div>
            <div style="width:90px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><img src="{{itemImage}}" width="90"></div>
            <div class="clampcontainer">
              <div class="itemTitle linkColor">{{itemTitle}}</div>
              <p class="itemDescription">{{itemDescription}}...</p>
              <div class="fadeout"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
```

**Publication code:**

```
Meteor.publish('UserPlaylists', function() {
  var loggedinuser = Meteor.user();
  // Reveal ALL expenses if it's an admin who's logged in
  return Playlists.find({
    owner: loggedinuser._id
  });
});


// Publish public playlists, as long as they're both public and from the same company
Meteor.publish('PublicPlaylists', function() {
  var loggedinuser = Meteor.user();
  var companyid = loggedinuser.userofcompanyid;
  // Reveal ALL expenses if it's an admin who's logged in
  return Playlists.find({
    companyid: companyid,
    published: true
  });
});

// Publishes absolutely all expenses for superadmins
Meteor.publish('Playlists', function() {
  var loggedinuser = Meteor.user();
  if (loggedinuser.issuperadmin) {
    return Playlists.find({});
  }

});
```

**Subscribing to the publications in the template js:**

```
Template.Playlists.onCreated(function playlistsOnCreated() {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
    self.subscribe('UserPlaylists');
    self.subscribe('PublicPlaylists');
    self.subscribe('UserPlaylistItems');
    self.subscribe('PublicPlaylistItems');
  });
});
```

**The playlists helper:**

```
  playlists() {
    return Playlists.find({}, {
      sort: {
        timestamp: -1
      }
    });
  },
```

**The playlistItems helper:**

```
  playlistItems(playlistid) {
    return PlaylistItems.find({
      playlistid: playlistid
    }, {
      sort: {
        timestamp: -1
      }
    });
  },
```

Comment: please add your publication and template code so we can see if the reactivity is missing due to wrong publication or missing ractive variables.

Comment: I have improvised your code for much better readability and performance. You are free to change it back.

Comment: Smells like you get your `Items` from a `Method` instead of a Publication. Editing your question to answer @Jankapunkt's comment would clear this point.

Comment: @AnkurSoni, thank you, I'm a novice as you can see, but I found your alteration very efficient/interesting!

Comment: @ghybs, the template loops through "playlists" ("the playlists helper" pasted above). Then we loop through playlistitems of that id (the "playlistItems" helper, pasted above.

How would I get my playlistitems from a publication? (I tried "{{each PublicPlaylists" and "{{each UserPlaylists}}" in the template but both brought back nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Jankapunkt, I've added the publication, subscription and template code.

Comment: @AnkurSoni, it's interesting to note your alteration:

    if (!readItems) {
      return false;
    }

... is reactive when 0 subscribers goes to 1 subscriber, but the array code underneath that checks if it's _this_ subscriber is still not reactive.

Comment: @HCapello good now you need only to clarify to which of the collections your first code snippet is related to (Playlist, PlaylistItems etc.)?